# How to solve list index out of range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to read a CSV file save to list and count the numbers of every word, but I got some error is about list index out of range in Python.

I have 21291918 rows in the CSV file. The following is a screenshot of the CSV file.

[image]

[image]

The following is my code:

```
from datetime import date,datetime
import numpy as np
import xlrd
import codecs
import time
import re
import os
import jieba
from itertools import repeat
import sys
import csv
maxInt = sys.maxsize

while True:
    # decrease the maxInt value by factor 10 
    # as long as the OverflowError occurs.

    try:
        csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
        break
    except OverflowError:
        maxInt = int(maxInt/10)

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000000)


jieba.load_userdict('./data/dict.txt')

file_name = 'Real/B_Seg_output.csv'

with open (file_name, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    column = [row[0] for row in reader]
    author_list = list(column)

#print(author_list)
print('-'*30)

with open('Real/Other_Content_Count_All.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write('回復內容\n')

j=0
cnt = set(author_list)
for i in cnt:
    j += 1
    print(j)
    if(j % 10000 == 0):
        print('*'*10+str(j)+" is sleeping"+'*'*10)
        time.sleep(10)

    if author_list.count(i)>0:
        #print(i+',',author_list.count(i))
        #print(i)
        #print(author_list.count(i))
        with open('Real/First_Author_Count_All.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            csvfile.write(i+','+str(author_list.count(i))+'\n')
```

When I run this code, I got the following problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\count_All_Other_Content.py", line 38, in <module>
    column = [row[0] for row in reader]
  File ".\count_All_Other_Content.py", line 38, in <listcomp>
    column = [row[0] for row in reader]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

[image]

I searched the related problems. I suspected the reason is some lines have space value.

However, I cannot find the solution. And then, I suspected the rows of CSV is over than list limit.

I need to use this CSV file to count the number of occurrences of each word. I don't know what to solve.

Comment: It looks like there's an empty row in the file.  So, check for it.

Comment: like tom says, some rows may just be empty list, so the `0` index will not even exist. you can filter them out.

`column = [row[0] for row in reader if row]`

Comment: What do you need recursion for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just change your `column = [row[0] for row in reader]` line to one of these:

- `column = [row[0] if row else None for row in reader]` - This will preserve the indexes if that's important
- `column = [row[0] for row in reader if row]` - This will skip the empty rows

If the header is empty then it raises an IndexError when you try to access any items.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in reader:
    if len(row[0]) > 0:
        column = row[0]
    else:
        pass
```

You can add this line before author_list and after reader lines. So that if checks if something is on there, it takes it. Otherwise it passes to other rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fastest way to do this is just to use readlines like this:

```
with f as open('myfile'):
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Now *lines* is a list of all the lines in the file, if a line is empty you will have an empty string (' ') in the list and you can easily check that. You can also delete '\r' and '\n' characters.

If you want to count the number of different words you can just use `len(set(lines))`. If you want the count of each one instead you can use numpy.unique function that will give you the array of unique values and also the count of each one.